# How to invoke a method of js object after invoking another method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods

I often saw this code in jQuery.

```
$('div').action1().delay(miliseconds).action2();
```

I could realize it in one level action in the following code.

```
function $(id) {
   var $ =  document.getElementById(id);

   $.action1 = function() {

   };

  return $;

}
```

How to write the method `delay()` and `action2()` so that I could use them this way?

```
$('div').action1().delay(miliseconds).action2();
```

Comment: The `.delay()` action only works for animations (unless you're manually using `.queue()` with a callback), is this what you're trying to do, or something else?

Comment: +1 Nick, I think he's specifically asking about chaining and plugins, and using .delay() as an example of something that's already included in jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

What you're referring to is called chaining.  Aside from the fact that delay is used for animations, the key point to remember is to return `this` from your function.

If you'd like to see how specific jQuery functions work, check out the code for `removeClass`:

```
removeClass: function( value ) {
    if ( jQuery.isFunction(value) ) {
        return this.each(function(i) {
            var self = jQuery(this);
            self.removeClass( value.call(this, i, self.attr("class")) );
        });
    }

    if ( (value && typeof value === "string") || value === undefined ) {
        var classNames = (value || "").split(rspace);

        for ( var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++ ) {
            var elem = this[i];

            if ( elem.nodeType === 1 && elem.className ) {
                if ( value ) {
                    var className = (" " + elem.className + " ").replace(rclass, " ");
                    for ( var c = 0, cl = classNames.length; c < cl; c++ ) {
                        className = className.replace(" " + classNames[c] + " ", " ");
                    }
                    elem.className = jQuery.trim( className );

                } else {
                    elem.className = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return this;
},
```

Notice the `return this;` at the end?  That's allowing you to call `$('#myelement').removeClass('highlight').someOtherFunction()`, because at the end of the removeClass, you're still operating on the jQuery object itself.

If you'd like to examine other functions, check out the development version (unminified) of jQuery: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js

Edit: to more fully answer your question, you can write your functions to allow chaining in the following way (include after your jQuery include):

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        action1: function() { return this; },
        action2: function() { return this; }
    })(jQuery);
```

This is essentially creating your own plugin.  You can find a lot of tutorials online for how to do so, or open a plugin you already have an take a look at it.

Here is one simple tutorial: http://www.queness.com/post/112/a-really-simple-jquery-plugin-tutorial

Edit2: Without getting too far into creating jQuery plugins (since your questions is about javascript in general), I just wanted to mention that if you're doing a jQuery plugin, you'll want to do:
`return this.each(function() {});`
so your function performs on all elements chosen by the selector.

Answer (score 1):

[`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) is used for animations

Sure there's other ways you can do this, but jQuery is chainable in an awesome way. That is, you don't have to write a bunch of anonymous functions or custom callbacks if you don't want to. **Convenience in chaining!**

On the other hand, if you actually want to customize the callbacks of animations, you can!

```
$('#foo').slideDown(500, function(){
  alert('foo is visible now!');
});
```

Check out the [jQuery Effects API](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) for more information.

It might be helpful to look at JavaScript's native [`setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) function, too.